# No signature of method error while testing in grails

Tags: grails, spock

I have a very simple code in my test:

```
    expect:
        String test = "test123"
        myHelper.myMethod(test) == "test"
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
|  groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.some.helper.MyHelper.myMethod() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [test123] Possible solutions: myMethod(java.lang.String)
        at com.some.helper.MyHelperSpec.test (MyHelperSpec.groovy:245)
```

My method expects a String and I'm passing a string. What am I missing here? FWIW, I'm using grails 2.5.3

Comment: This is tricky :) Could you please share more information with us so we can try to reproduce your error?

Comment: quite sure it's about static function declaration. but to be clear share example of `myMethod` declaration in `MyHelper` class and how you declare/create `myHelper` variable...